# Download xlsx file using php

Tags: php, file, header, xlsx

I need make `xlsx` file download from my site (but not from directly open file url like this: `http://site.com/file.xlsx` )

So, this is php code

```
        $file = "somefile.xlsx";
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
```

file is downloaded, his extension is `.xlsx`, but when trying open this file in ms excel, file not opened and I got error : `excel cannot open the file.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid`

Tell please, why this happened? where I am wrong?

Comment: What does the downloaded file contain?

Comment: If Excel complaints that the file does not contain a valid spreadsheet, we must assume it knows what it's talking about. There're two possibilities: `somefile.xlsx` is not valid to begin with, or some junk gets added in the download process. If you save the *downloaded* file to disk and open with a text editor (not Excel) you might be able to spot what does not belong to there.

Comment: @ Pekka 웃 ,  Álvaro --- Thanks very much, I get error.

Comment: Please also note that if you dont want the file to be accessible through a direct link you should place that file outside the webserver root or configure your webserver to disallow that filetype to be downloaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After many years, I got same problem, and after searching, I got here again ))

This is solution, that worked for me:

```
$file = "somefile.xlsx";
// define file $mime type here
ob_end_clean(); // this is solution
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 4):

You must be using this code in middle of some other file.

The problem with headers is they need to be set first on a page. They will not work if you have even 1 single space echoing before them. So you need to ob_clean() [clean the buffer] before you are setting headers

Try

```
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    $file = "somefile.xlsx";
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
```

Comment: Using `flush()` still resulted in an error. Using `ob_clean()` by itself before setting the headers worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Remove:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

Add at the end of code:

```
exit();
```

The issue is that flush() will also throw in your *.xlsx file content some garbage it has in it and that will corupt your file, even if you use ob_clean();

For a better understanding go to php.net and read the difference between flush(), ob_flush() and find that you didn't even need them in the first case. Therefore you won't need the ob_clean() too.

Comment: @OTARIKI I searched for an working code, I found yours, fixed it and used it. That's why I also added the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fileLocation)."\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileLocation)); //Remove

    ob_clean();
    flush();

    readfile($fileLocation);
```